# VisualVM profiler - не могу сделать snapshot

Tags: java, visualvm

Пытаюсь разобраться, почему VisualVM не может сделать snapshot.
Порядок действий:

- Profiler -> Memory settings -> Record allocations stack traces
- Profiler -> Profile -> Memory
- Profiler -> Snapshot

Выдает ошибку `Failed to obtain results snapshot. The profiled application terminated`

Код

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());

        try {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                arrayList.add(random.nextInt());
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {

        }
    }
}
```

И ссылка на огромный лог, который здесь не помещается https://mega.nz/#!4FAzUJLL!7TsC1wgh0g9Vw4wMfh8QlgMGfLLP8s_J2-zMDU_3s0E

Второй день пытаюсь узнать, в чем проблема. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Это ошибка JDK: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8147451

Судя по комментариям, в JDK 9 не воспроизводится, 9-ка еще в разработке, но можете попробовать: https://jdk9.java.net/download/

Comment: Не знаешь, там уже есть своя поддержка json?

Comment: @АлексейПересторонин не пробовал, недавно слышал что вроде как в 10-ую хотят перенести. А так Gson полностью устраивает.

Comment: @АлексейПересторонин Дропнули, цитата: "We may reconsider this JEP for JDK 10 or a later release, especially if
new language features such as value types and generics over primitive
types (JEP 218) enable a more compact and expressive API." http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk9-dev/2014-December/001670.html

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка `Failed to obtain results snapshot. The profiled application terminated`
Означает что SnapShot не может быть получен так как приложение остановлено.
Во время профилирования ваша программа пытается получить некоторый classloader `sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor{41-1}`,
при этом Profiler Agent сообщает что имя класса есть null
однако программа Visual VM, а конкретно её Profiler Agent Communication Thread при получении SnapShot'а залезает в те части программы где находятся её контрольные значения(Вероятно) что вызывает SIGSEGV и последующий вылет ошибки.